# Can't access android device from DDMS

Tags: android, device, ddms

My device is showing on DDMS device list but I cannot do anything with it. For example, file explorer shows nothing and log cat is blank. I just tried to take screenshot, and eclipse just crashed. I of course, made the device in debug usb mode. It seems like a device driver problem but I didn't have any problem with upgrading and rooting this phone.

Is there anything I need to do to the device to make it communicate with DDMS?

UPDATE: I found another visible symptom with my Android device. If I connect it to PC, some of my windows explorer freeze as well. So clearly this is a device driver (SAMSUNG GALAXY S) problem. Maybe it's related to rooting or upgrading since I didn't notice this until I upgraded & rooted my device lately.

UPDATE2: I found a resolution and I could **[use Remote ADB to connect the device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8569496/931170)** After running the app in the device, you can type following from PC Command to make it connected to DDMS.

```
adb connect 192.168.xxx.xxx:5555
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I have had similar problems, I first unplug the device, turn off debugging, then turn it back on. Sometimes this alone works. Other times, an Android SDK update is needed.

Comment: I've already tried them without any success. At this point, I suspect USB driver but strangely DDMS recognizes the device...Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In the DDMS view (as opposed to the Java view), have you tried selecting the device? It's not entirely intuitive, but the device needs to be highlighted for Logcat to show output.

Comment: I am familiar with that part. Of course, I selected the device. Actually, eclipse itself seems to freeze whenever I connect the device to PC.