# Android Development on Samsung Galaxy S

Tags: android, debugging, mode, galaxy

I am trying to test my Android apps in my Samsung Galaxy S i9000 but I dont know why, I cant. It doesn't appear in the Devices tab on Eclipse.
I've downloaded the Google Drivers via SDK Manager, I've got the Samsung Drivers for Windows x64, I've put it in debugging mode, and still nothing.

This is weird, because some time ago, but in another computer, I was able to do this with my old Xperia X8 and Nexus S, with no problem.

This phone is rooted and has a MIUI Rom on it, but my old phones were rooted and had cooked rooms too, and worked perfectly.

Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've had [the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305939/cant-access-android-device-from-ddms) My system does not even complain about driver but whole system became weird when the phone was connected via USB. Thanks to Jakar's answer, however, I installed Remote ADB and it's working great.

Comment: I don't like Remote ADB, it's not intuitive and i don't know very well how to use it when programming in eclipse. :(

Comment: You would just open remote ADB, then enter a port number (5554 works), then click `Apply`. Then on your computer, click Start then run cmd.exe then on the next screen of the app, it will tell you something like `adb tcpip 5554` and `adb connect 192.168.1.65:5554`. Type both commands into your CMD window. Then do `adb devices` and it should list something like `192.168.1.65:5554`. If it does that, then Eclipse will act the same as if you had it plugged in via USB. This does have to be on Wi-Fi, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your computer, go to the start menu and type `devmgmt.msc` (it runs Device Management. There should then be a yellow exclamation-point box thing and a name of a driver (for the one that's missing). If there exists that issue, please comment with the exact name of the missing driver. If that does not appear there, then that means it's an issue with the MIUI rom, not so much the drivers.

I personally had some custom roms that I could not get to support ADB.

Though, if I installed "Remote ADB" from the Android Market, that would work via Wi-Fi even without USB drivers, so that is another recommendation.

Comment: Just as you said, yellow exclamation of a missing driver: http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/3644/driversgs.jpg But this is weird, because I have installed Samsung drivers from their page.

Comment: But still dont know how to fix this, the Samsung driver don't fix it, what should I do?

Comment: @koneX You should uninstall all of your Android related drivers (other than from the Android SDK). Meaning if you have drivers for Motorola or HTC, uninstall those from your computer. Also uninstall the Samsung ones of course. Reboot your computer. Then re-install the correct Samsung drivers from samsung.com/support then open your SDK manager and make absolutely sure that `Google USB Driver Package` is on Rev 4. If not, update it. Doing those steps fixed this problem for me, anyway.

Comment: If that doesn't help you could try contacting the MIUI developer on XDA or you could post your question on XDA as it may be an issue caused by the custom rom rather than the device itself.

Answer (score 1):

Go settings on phone, manage applications, development, usb debug is off by default.

Comment: No it's not that. I know because I have the same problem.

Comment: Read the topic question, I said i put it in debugging mode. But thanks! :)